# How to sum time between dates if difference is less than 10 minutes

Tags: ios, sql, database, macos, core-data

I have model Activity, and i am storing timeInterval/NSDate when user does some activity, there could be situation when user will take a break for 15 minutes, and will back. I would like to sum time between activities only if difference is less than 10 minutes between them and measure real time of his work. How can i create NSPredicate to achieve that?

Comment: Operatin on Array would be easy, but i would like to write query for the database to achieve that with in an optimized way

Comment: I am thinking a record of all actions with dates\times. Then a Group By search run with a commutative search, with the where clause being the indicator if the value should be displayed or not. Then using a SUM() over the commutative column. (Grrr...Example Coming).

Comment: Probably i found a solution, i added another field to record with "timeIntervalToPreviousRow", then during inserting a new row, i am updating previous and next row difference to rows, then i am able to exclude this time when difference is more than 10 minutes

Comment: An example is provided below.

Comment: @mientus I think your approach is reasonable and should work well.

Answer (score -1):

Nailed it for you. What I believe is a good example below.

```
-- Set Employee ID And Date Required Here
DECLARE @ID INT = 7;
DECLARE @Date SMALLDATETIME = '20150615';

--create our table
DECLARE @TableRows TABLE
(
ID TINYINT,
ActionLog SMALLDATETIME
);

-- Insert some data
INSERT INTO @TableRows
VALUES
(10,'20150615 16:01:00'),
(7,'20150615 16:02:00'),
(7,'20150615 16:04:00'),
(10,'20150615 16:04:00'),
(10,'20150615 16:23:00'),
(10,'20150615 16:25:00'),
(10,'20150615 16:26:00');

-- First CTE for Row Numbers
WITH RowNumCTE
AS
(SELECT 
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ActionLog) AS RowNum
    , ActionLog
FROM 
    @TableRows
WHERE
    ID = @ID AND
    datediff(day, @Date, ActionLog) = 0
)

-- SUM of all the Minutes

SELECT 
    SUM(DATEDIFF(MINUTE,t2.ActionLog,t1.ActionLog)) as Mins
FROM RowNumCTE t1
    LEFT JOIN RowNumCTE t2 ON T1.RowNum = T2.RowNum + 1
WHERE
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE,t2.ActionLog,t1.ActionLog) < 10
```

Answer (score -1):

A better, faster example. This uses LEAD window function (Created in SQL 2012).

```
-- Set Required Date Here
DECLARE @Date SMALLDATETIME = '20150615';

--create our table
DECLARE @TableRows TABLE
(
TableID INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
ID TINYINT,
ActionLog SMALLDATETIME
);

-- Insert some data
INSERT INTO @TableRows
VALUES
(10,'20150615 16:01:00'),
(7,'20150615 16:02:00'),
(7,'20150615 16:04:00'),
(10,'20150615 16:04:00'),
(10,'20150615 16:23:00'),
(10,'20150615 16:25:00'),
(10,'20150615 16:26:00');

-- First CTE for Row Numbers (To force the LEAD first in the QEP)
WITH AllMinsCTE
AS
(SELECT 
    ID AS EmployeeID,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, ActionLog, LEAD(ActionLog) OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY id, actionlog)) as Mins
FROM 
    @TableRows
WHERE
    datediff(day, @Date, ActionLog) = 0
)

SELECT 
    EmployeeID, 
    SUM(AllMinsCTE.Mins) as Mins FROM AllMinsCTE
WHERE
    AllMinsCTE.Mins < 10
Group BY EmployeeID;
```